# How to make Paypal button invoke "live" functionality?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-buttons

Following the code from https://www.paypal.com/buttons, I follow the "Smart Buttons" link, generate and copy the code, so I add the following to our payments page (with our actual clientID instead of the XXXXXX....):

```
<div id="smart-button-container">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  function initPayPalButton() {
    paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
        shape: 'rect',
        color: 'gold',
        layout: 'vertical',
        label: 'paypal',
    },

    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{"description":"Subscription to our service","amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":10}}]
      });
    },

    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
      });
    },

    onError: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  }
initPayPalButton();
</script>
```

The button seems to work, in that it opens the Paypal payment window; but the payment does not seem to take effect.

I then notice what I believe would be the reason:  the URL of the Paypal payment window reads `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow .....`

Question:  how do I set up the code to enable the "live" functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a Sandbox Client ID.

Obtain your Live Client ID from the "Live" tab of https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications

Comment: Preston: this tells me that it is the credentials for `Express Checkout via Braintree SDK Credentials`.  I have no idea what that is (seems like Paypal has _N_ different payment/checkout mechanisms, and for the life of me I cannot make sense of all the little pieces I see on their various documentation pages :‒( ).  It gives me an access token that looks like `access_token$production$some_hex$some_longer_hex`

Comment: You are not using Braintree. Scroll to the top of the page.